# Can you use an NSManagedObject outside of it's context's performBlock?

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

NSManagedObjectContext's have had the performBlock: and performBlockAndWait: methods added to help make concurrency easier.  I've been using them -- potentially fairly naively -- and I just realized that there's a question I've never really asked.

If I create an NSManagedObject subclass inside one of the performBlock methods, it's 'home' thread is the thread of it's parent context -- which in the case of the NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType is probably an independent thread I have no other access to.

So do I need to do a performBlock call just to access the data contained inside my managed objects?  Or is there a background magic going on to help protect me in the case of using getters?  (Or setters, though that seems like a bad idea...)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`NSManagedObject` is not supposed to be used outside of its `managedObjectContext`s thread/queue (sometime it works and some times you crash ==> don't do it).

CoreData does not guarantee safe read access to the object.

To access an object owned by a "private queue" context, always use either `[context performBlock:...]` or `[context performBlockAndWait:...]`, unless you access its `objectID` or `managedObjectContext` properties.

Comment: Thanks, pretty much what I was thinking was necessary... I was hoping I was wrong.  I need to re-watch the WWDC video where they introduced the technique, because I don't remember them having to do that...  Then again, I suspect there are a lot of WWDC videos that I need to re-watch.

Comment: I'd just like to add that Apple engineers explicitly state that reads on `NSManagedObject` are not thread-safe because core data does  caching, and cache writes are not thread safe

Answer (score 9):

You do need to use `performBlock:` or `performBlockAndWait:`, but there's one exception. If you're using `NSMainQueueConcurrencyType` **and** you are using the managed object on the main queue, you can access it directly, with no block. This can be a great convenience when you need to update your UI from a managed object, or vice versa.

Comment: Another exception is `NSConfinementConcurrencyType` which is similar to main queue, only to a specific thread (the "old" version of managed contexts)

Comment: I guess I should have worded my question better, since it essentially ONLY pertains to NSPrivateQueue and NSMainQueue types... the even then, primarily to the private queue version thanks to this wonderful exception.